# PHP Referrer and Wordpress wp_get_referer() not working for external URLS

Tags: php, wordpress

Getting a referrer URL using PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] or using Wordpress wp_get_referer() is not working for external URLs, example: if an user click on a links on test.com that opens abcdef.com, at abcdef.com the referrer url from test.com is blank but when i navigate inside abcdef.com the referrer url works correctly.

Is this a new feature?